# $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ closed and connected. Prove $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid d(x, A) \le \varepsilon\}$ is path-connected

Tags: general-topology

I've encountered the following question:

Say $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed and connected set. Prove $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid d(x, A) \le \varepsilon\}$ is **path**-connected.

I'm not really sure how to approach this question. It appears under the section of Compactness.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I really liked this exercise. So neat. Where did you found it? (any book, etc?)

Comment: Yes, It appeared on "Elementary Topology - Problem Textbook" by O. Ya. Viro, O.A.Ivanov, N.Yu.Netsvetaev, V.M.Kharlamov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For any connected (nonvoid) subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the set $\{x\ | \ d(x,A) < \epsilon\}$ is connected, since it is the union $\cup_{a\in A} B(a,\epsilon)$, every ball $B(a,\epsilon)$ is connected, and also $A$ is connected ( think of a fishbone). Moreover, $\{x\ | \ d(x,A) < \epsilon\}$ is open, therefore, $\{x\ | \ d(x,A) < \epsilon\}$ is $path\ connected$. 
Connect any point $y$ in  $\{x\ | \ d(x,A) \le \epsilon\}$ with a closest point in $a \in \bar A$, the half open segment $(y,a]$ will lie in $\{x\ | \ d(x,A) < \epsilon\}$ (this is the idea of @Omnomnomnom ).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | d(x, A) \le \varepsilon\}$.  Consider any $x_1,x_2 \in S$.  There exist points $y_1,y_2 \in A$ such that $d(x_i,y_i) \leq \epsilon$ for $i = 1,2$.

- Show that there is a path connecting $x_i$ and $y_i$ for $i = 1,2$.
- Show that there is a path connecting $y_1$ to $y_2$
- Conclude that there is a path connecting $x_1$ to $x_2$

For the first part, we can consider the path
$$
x(t) = (1-t)x_i + t y_i, \quad t \in [0,1]
$$

Comment: Thank you. I tried to solve the second part and I'm not sure if I'm right.
$A \subseteq T := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n |d(x,A) < \varepsilon\}$. $T$ is connected since $T$ is a union of open balls(connected) that each one of them intersect with $A$(connected). $T$ is also locally path-connected(union of balls). Since $T$ is both connected and locally-path-connected then $T$ is path-connected. Then since $y_1, y_2 \in T \subseteq S$  there is a path connecting $y_1$ and $y_2$.
Am I correct?
If this really is the solution it's weird that it appears under the section "Compactness".

Comment: It is strange that it is under the section "compactness", but maybe there's another question that uses this result.  Your proof makes sense geometrically, but it doesn't seem rigorous to me as stated.

Comment: This argument works for any set $A$, not necessarily closed, doesn't it? Then why would they ask $A$ to be closed?

Comment: @A.G. $A$ needs to be closed for us to select the required $y_i$.

Comment: Right. So that's where compactness is used. We need to say that the function $|x-y|$ attains its minimum $\le\epsilon$ for some $y\in A$. Thanks.

Comment: @A.G. That can be done using just closedness. In fact, we're not given that $A$ is compact, though we could restrict our consideration to a bounded subset and apply Heine Borel.  It's still easier to just use the fact that $A$ is closed.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I mean the distance from $x$ to $A$ is $\le\epsilon$, the set $A\cap B_\epsilon(x)$ is compact, then the minimum attained for some $y\in A\cap B_\epsilon(x)\subset A$.

Comment: Right, so you're using the fact that *closed + bounded = compact*.  That's Heine Borel.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: "Show that there is a path connecting $y_1$ to $y_2$ "  ... that is problematic, as $A$ is not assumed to be path connected.   I would say this is not a valid  hint the way it stands.

Comment: To echo @orangeskid, the standard non path-connected connected set, the topologist sine curve, is a suitable $A$ for which this method doesn't work.

Comment: Now that I read the comment of @amirbd89: , it looks that he after all made good of the hint of  Omnomnomnom... just like in my solution...turns out the hint works after all

Comment: @orangeskid I missed that detail, but I'm glad the hint still works

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Yes, I like it  especially because for any $\epsilon >0$ we can have a path  between $y_1$ and $y_2$  in  $A_{\epsilon}$, but possibly not in $A$, quite puzzling.